# Android Programming: Bluetooth connection refused on OS Version 4.1.1

Tags: android

In android application we are using Bluetooth connectivity with some of medical devices.

To do this we have used below code

```
BluetoothDevice zee = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(bluetoothAddress);
Method m = (Method) zee.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
result = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(zee, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

or some condition, if the above code get failed then we use below code

```
String bluetooth_address="";
bluetooth_address=bluetoothAddress;
BluetoothDevice zee = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(bluetooth_address);
result = zee.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( getSerialPortUUID() );
```

both codes are working fine up to 4.0 android OS.

But on Android OS 4.1.1 it is now getting issue like “`Connection Refused`”.

Please help.

Comment: No I did not try in 4.2.1

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer here... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15919

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I solved this issue by calling insecure RF comm Socket like

```
String bluetooth_address="";
bluetooth_address=bluetoothAddress;
BluetoothDevice zee = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(bluetooth_address);
//result = zee.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( getSerialPortUUID() );
result = zee.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(getSerialPortUUID());
```

Answer (score 1):

There were issues with bluetooth in version 4.2 and presumably 4.1.1. In version 4.2.1 they have been resolved. Check http://crave.cnet.co.uk/mobiles/android-4-2-1-update-brings-back-december-fixes-bluetooth-50009859/. Try in 4.2.1